# Trying to start a node.js app using npm start but get err_empty_response in browser

Tags: node.js, npm

I cloned a node.js application from an internal repo that is working just fine for other developers, but not for me. This is my FIRST node app that I've been asked to work on, but have no clue how to debug it. After getting a bunch of other errors, I finally fixed everything (the cloning and dependencies part), and when I do an npm start, I can see that the app is started and the cursor blinking in the command prompt, but when I try to browser to that path (http://localhost:8000/service) - I don't get any response back in the browser except a message:

```
This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I don't see any error in the console. I tried using Postman, and get the following message:

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to localhost:8000/service/.
```

The code in my package.js is as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
"ansc-core": "^1.8.2",
"lodash": "~4.17.0",
"request": "~2.87.0",
"abcdef": "^1.6.1",
"underscore": "^1.9.1"
 },
```

The code in my ansc.json (where the port number is set) is:

```
"port":8000,
"server_ssl_key_store": "sss/xxx/yyyy/zzz.43",
"server_ssl_key_store_password": "",
"cpu_count": 1
}
```

The code in service.js is:

```
const $ = require('abcdefg').xxxxxx;

class Service {
constructor() {
    console.log("in service constructor");
    $.info({ service: 'up' });
}


  findAll() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {

        resolve([]);

    });
  }
}

module.exports = Service;
```

The code in routes.js which calls service is:

```
const Service = require('./service');
const $ = require('abcdefg').xxxxxx;

const service = new Service();

const Routes = {

getEntity(req, res) {
    service.findAll().then((items) => {
        console.log("inside getentity");
        res.send(items);
    }).catch((error) => {
        $.error(error);
        res.status(500).send(error);
    });
    }
 };

 module.exports = Routes;
```

Finally the index.js (which is the app's entrypoint) is:

```
  const ansc = require('ansc-core');
  const routes = require('./src/service/routes');

 ansc.routes((app) => {
  console.log("before app get");
  app.get('/service', routes.getEntity);
 }).start();

module.exports = ansc;
```

Has anyone else run into this or similar issue?

Comment: Stupid error on my part - it was resolved by changing from http to https!

Answer (score 1):

Stupid error on my part - it was resolved by changing from http to https!